# Overlaying points and controlling size with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot some point estimates with a couple of interval estimates around them, and then to superimpose the true point values using a different color and size, with a legend for the color.

I've tried lots of things. If I just use a new call to geom_point, I can't figure out how to add a legend. Therefore, my current approach resorts to stacking the data on top of itself, which is clumsy. Even then, the graph comes out wrong with big blue points for the True values, with the desired orange points on top of them.

I'd appreciate any help I can get.

```
nms <- c("2.5%","25%","50%","75%","97.5%","dose","truep")
a <- c(9.00614679684893e-    44,0.000123271800672435,0.0339603711049475,0.187721170170911,0.67452033450121,5,0.040752445325937)
b <- c(1.59502878028266e-25,0.00328588588499889,0.0738203422543555,0.25210200886225,0.714843425007051,10,0.0885844107052267)
cc <- c(1.41975723605948e-14,0.0184599181547097,0.118284929584256,0.311068595276067,0.74339745948793,15,0.141941915501108)
d <- c(0.0311851190805834,0.154722028150561,0.299318020818234,0.50887634580605,0.838779816278485,25,0.359181624981881)
e <- c(0.0529617924263383,0.289588386297245,0.566777817134668,0.883959271416755,0.999999999999317,40,0.680133380561602)
f <- c(0.0598904847882839,0.327655201251564,0.640100529843672,0.950060245074853,1,50,0.768120635812406)
g <- c(0.0641613025760661,0.355626055560067,0.686504841650593,0.978023943968809,1,60,0.823805809980712)

p <- as.data.frame(t(data.frame(a, b, cc, d, e, f, g)))
names(p) <- nms

# Faff duplicating data
p$truep <- 1.2 * p$truep
p2 <- p
p2[, 1:5] <- p$truep # truep is known, so there are no intervals

p3 <- rbind(p2, p)
p3$wh <- rep((c(2, 3)), each=nrow(p))
p3$col <- rep(c("orange", "blue"), each=nrow(p))

ggplot(p3, aes(dose, `50%`)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=wh, color=col)) +
  scale_size(range=c(5, 7), guide="none") +
  scale_color_manual(name="", labels=c("Prior", "True"), values=c("blue", "orange")) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin=`2.5%`, ymax=`97.5%`, x=dose), color="blue") +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin=`25%`, ymax=`75%`, x=dose), color="blue", size=2) +
  geom_point(aes(dose, truep), color="orange") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=12), axis.title.x=element_text(size=14),
    axis.text.y=element_text(size=12), axis.title.y=element_text(size=14),
    legend.text=element_text(size=12))
```

R 3.3.1, ggplot2_2.1.1

Thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by splitting the dataset in two parts:

```
library(dplyr)

priors <- p%>%
  mutate(datatype = 'Prior')

truevals <-  p%>%
  select(dose, truep)%>%
  mutate(datatype = 'True')


ggplot(truevals, aes(x = dose, y = truep, colour = datatype))+
  geom_pointrange(data = priors, aes(ymin=`25%`, ymax=`75%`, y = `50%`), size=1.5) +
  geom_pointrange(data = priors, aes(ymin=`2.5%`, ymax=`97.5%`, y = `50%`))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_color_manual(name="", values=c("Prior" = "blue", "True" = "orange")) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=12), axis.title.x=element_text(size=14),
        axis.text.y=element_text(size=12), axis.title.y=element_text(size=14),
        legend.text=element_text(size=12))
```

First we plot the two pointranges based on the dataset with priors. Then the actual values. By adding a row with the datatype to both datasets we can add the legend. The result is this graph:
[image]

Comment: Thank you! I now have the plot I want.

Answer (score 0):

For the method `ggplot2::geom_point()` there is a `show.legend` attribute which is `NA` by default so setting this to `TRUE` should help.

You can add a legend using the labels attribute as follows:

```
ggplot2::scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "black",
                           labels = c("Number of people",
                                      "Number of birds"))
```

You are already doing this with `labels=c("Prior", "True")`

You can also change the look of the legend with:

```
ggplot2::theme(legend.position = "bottom",
               legend.text = ggplot2::element_text(size = 22),
               legend.box = "horizontal",
               legend.key = ggplot2::element_blank())
```

Comment: I fought for ages with scale_fill_manual and scale_color_manual but couldn't get the legends to appear. The solution from Jeroen Boeye works but resorts to splitting the data in 2. Thanks for your suggestion, tho.